# How to change height of a specific cell without affecting its row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Base on the snippet. I want that the "Contract" stage will have a higher height compared to other cells.

I tried to use:

```
td.active{
    height:100px;
}
```

but it affects all the cells, and making all the cells height equal to `100px`.

This should be the desired output: [image]

```css
#disposition tr:nth-child(2){
  border-bottom: 3px #818286 solid;
  font-size: 15px;
}



#disposition tr:nth-child(1) td{
  background-color: gray;
  color:white;

  border: 3px white solid;
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(20deg);

  height: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#disposition tr:nth-child(1) td.done{
  background-color: #249fda;
}
#disposition tr:nth-child(1) td.active{
  background-color: #249fda;
}
#disposition td{
  text-align: center;
}
#disposition td i{
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
}
#disposition td.active-box{
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table" id="disposition">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td class="done">
         <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </td>
        <td class="done">
          <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </td>
        <td class="done">
          <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true">    </i>
        </td>
        <td class="active" style="">
          <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </td>
        <td>
          <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </td>
        <td>
          <i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </td>
        <td>
          <i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="stage-names">
                                <td>Application</td>
                                          <td>Documents</td>
                                          <td>Under Review</td>
                                        <td title="Contracts make it all legal and binding for both sides." style="color: #249fda; font-family:'CooperHewitt-BoldItalic'">Contracts</td>
                                          <td>Underwriting </td>
                                          <td>Funding</td>
                                          <td>Payback</td>
                        </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
```

Comment: You need to have a container inside your cells, which is specifically sized and tied to the bottom.  The cells are always going to grow to fit the row, that's how tables work.

Comment: You don't use tables for layout, like almost everyone was saying back in the 90's...

Answer (score 0):

What Goli has said is probably right, at least in my experience with css. You also don't want an extra `style=""`in-line.

You may want to try adding in some simple Javascript stuff to get it to dynamically change. Try using `document.getElementsByTagName` and setting the style.width to your desired amount. 
(If you haven't used JS before W3 can walk you through the basics easily)